# How to install a vim plugin if a certain file extension is invoked

Tags: vim, plugins, macvim

I am trying to integrate vim into a larger part of my workflow, which includes scripting in Python and writing documents in LaTeX.  I install the YouCompleteMe plugin to provide support for python coding with the following call in my .vimrc file

```
Plugin Valloric/YouCompleteMe
```

This works great when I am scripting in Python.  However, it causes to much interference when I am trying to draft LaTeX documents, which causes me to comment it out when I write in LaTeX.  I am fairly new at the syntax to script my .vimrc file, but is there some conditional statement I can use to install the plugin when I am writing a .py file and not when I am scripting a .tex file.  Something maybe like,

```
if file_type == '.py'
    Plugin Valloric/YouCompleteMe
fi
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are approaching the problem wrongly. The plugin exposes a number of options that allow you to decide exactly when to enable or disable it. See `:help youcompleteme-options`. Always start with the documentation.

Comment: I'll go ahead and recommend **vim-plug** as a modern alternative to Vundle. It has better performance and more features, while at the same time using a model similar to Vundle's, which should make it fairly easy to migrate from Vundle. In your specific case, it supports loading a plug-in only when a specific file type is loaded, using the `for` keyword. See https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#plug-options (and also the examples on the section above, there's one for only loading a plug-in for Clojure.)